# How to upload a chosen picture to external Mariadb using Mariadb/J-Connector in Android Studio?

Tags: android, image, kotlin, mariadb, external

I am writing an App for my diploma thesis and my partner has a external Mariadb. I can get and set data on the mariadb easily, but whenever we try to upload a picture we get the following problem, that I dont know how.

In my SetData Kotlin Class I have the following Code:

```
val query =
                "INSERT INTO Profiles (p_name, notification, unit, p_picture) VALUES ('$nam', $noti, $uni, $pic)"
            val stmt: Statement = connect!!.createStatement()
            val rs: ResultSet = stmt.executeQuery(query)
```

For the converting the chosen Picture into bitmaps, byteArrays & co. I have these lines:

```
bitmap = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(this.contentResolver, imageUri)

var bos = ByteArrayOutputStream()
    bitmap!!.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, bos)
    val bArray = bos.toByteArray()
    var p_picture: String = Base64.encodeToString(bArray, Base64.DEFAULT)
```

And then invocating my function where I transport the parameters for the already mentioned "query":

```
setData.setValues(p_name, p_notification, p_unit, p_picture)
```

When working without a picture (in this case p_picture is null) everything works fine and the database has a now entity. But if try the same thing with a chosen picture, I get the following error in the "query"-line:

> 2021-02-10 17:11:13.899 5974-5974/com.example.dbtesting E/Error 1: (conn=149) You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'nFS9W5McSY8lBsBvccmsItlfr82Y1mTSrKRfs0/6/09jspHZfN0kqzIzLu4OYB9ORJBTD23N7mJk

I have already reviewed other questions on SOF, but nobody wanted to the same thing, they always did it with PHP, while we have a "direct" connection to the external database.

Sideinformation: The datatype of picture in the database is a BLOP.

So my problem simply is, what have I to do, that the syntax is right. Maybe other datatype? Maybe do it differently? But to be honest we won't use PHP, since it is working everything except this little extra feature.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: use prepared statements. Not just for avoiding SQL injection (not only PHP is vulnerable). It help with separating data and SQL code.

Comment: @danblack What do you mean exactly? Your contribution is not really helping me to be honest

Comment: [prepared statements](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/prepared.html)

Comment: Thanks, I didnt found out how to do it with uploading Blob, but I got more hope now and I will test some features.

Comment: if doing over 16M of blob, look at increasing the [max_allowed_packet](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/server-system-variables/#max_allowed_packet)

Comment: @danblack Thank you for the prepared statement suggestion, it helped me a lot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is to use preparedStatements, with simple SQL Injections like the one I used in my question, you will not succeed. By using preparedStatements, now functions like setBinaryStream and getBinaryStream are possible and can/will be used for uploading/downloading BLOBs from extern databases. I hope some people will get an epiphany when reading my answer. The comment from @danblack helped me a lot, since I focused on preparedStatements and found some useful information.